# What is the best way to create small multiples in d3.js v6?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create small multiple bar charts that have different y-axis scales using d3 v6. There are a few examples out there (https://flowingdata.com/2014/10/15/linked-small-multiples/) of small multiples for previous versions of d3, but not v6, which seems to have a good number of changes implemented.

I don't have much experience with d3, so I am probably missing something obvious, but I can't get the bars to properly generate, the axes are generating (though I think I am generating them too many times on top of each other).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Small multiple bar charts</title>    
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='vis'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    // Set the sizing metrics
    var width = 150;
    var height = 120;
    var margin = {top: 15, right: 10, bottom: 40, left: 35};

    // Create the axes
    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                    .range([0, width])
                    .padding(0.1);
                
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                    .scale(xScale);

    // Load the data
    d3.csv('data.csv').then(function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.segment = d.segment;
            d.parameter = d.parameter;
            d.the_value = +d.the_value;
        });
        
        // set the x domain
        xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.segment; }));

        // group the data
        metrics = Array.from(
            d3.group(data, d => d.parameter), ([key, value]) => ({key, value})
        );

        // create a separate SVG object for each group
        var svg = d3.select('#vis').selectAll('svg')
                    .data(metrics)
                    .enter()
                    .append('svg');

        // loop over the data and create the bars
        metrics.forEach(function(d, i) {
            console.log(d);
            console.log(metrics);
            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(metrics, function(c) { return c.the_value; })]);

            svg.selectAll('.bar')
                .data(d)
                .enter().append('rect')
                .attr('class', 'bar')
                .attr('x', function(c) { return xScale(c.segment); })
                .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
                .attr('y', function(c) { return yScale(c.the_value); })
                .attr('height', function(c) { return height - yScale(c.the_value); })
                .attr('fill', 'teal');

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
                .call(xAxis)
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the data file:

```
segment,parameter,the_value
A,one,33
A,two,537723
A,three,14
A,four,5
A,five,0.093430759
B,one,76
B,two,137110
B,three,16
B,four,20
B,five,0.893868331
C,one,74
C,two,62020
C,three,25
C,four,14
C,five,0.862952872
```

Eventually I would also like to get the charts linked so that when series A is hovered on the first graph the value will display for each series on all of the graphs, but the first step is to get the visuals properly working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few small changes to get it working:

- When you set the `domain` on the `x` scale, you just need the unique segments e.g. A, B, C and not the full list of segments from the data.
- When you create the 5 SVGs you can class them so that you can refer to each separately when you loop through the values of the metrics. So the first small multiple has a class of `one`, the second small multiple has a class of `two` etc
- Reset the `y` domain using the set of `the_value`s from the metrics you're charting - i.e. use `d` not `metrics`
- When you loop `metrics` first `select` the small multiple for that metric and then `selectAll('.bar')`
- Pass `d.value` to `data` as this makes the references to `c.the_value` etc work properly
- To prevent adding the x axis multiple times, again `select` the SVG for the specific small multiple before `call(xAxis)` otherwise you add as many axes as there are parameters to each small multiple.

I faked up your data to include random data.

See the example below - maybe there's a smarter way to do it:

```js
// fake data
var data = ["A", "B", "C"].map(seg => {
  return ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"].map((par, ix) => {
    return {
      "segment": seg, 
      "parameter": par, 
      "the_value": (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1) * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 * ix) + 1)
    }
  });
}).flat();

// Set the sizing metrics
var width = 150;
var height = 120;
var margin = {top: 15, right: 10, bottom: 40, left: 35};

// Create the axes
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.1);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale);
  
// set the x domain
// put unique segments into the domain e.g. A, B, C
var uniqueSegments = Array.from(new Set(data.map(function(d) {return d.segment;} )));
xScale.domain(uniqueSegments);

// group the data
var metrics = Array.from(
  d3.group(data, d => d.parameter), ([key, value]) => ({key, value})
);

// create a separate SVG object for each group
// class each SVG with parameter from metrics
var svg = d3.select('#vis').selectAll('svg')
  .data(metrics)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.value[0].parameter;});

// loop over the data and create the bars
metrics.forEach(function(d, i) {
  //console.log(d);
  //console.log(metrics);
  // reset yScale domain based on the set of the_value's for these metrics
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(d.value, function(c) { return c.the_value; })]);

  // select the right svg for this set of metrics
  d3.select("svg." + d.value[0].parameter)
    .selectAll('.bar')
    .data(d.value) // use d.value to get to the the_value
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(c) { return xScale(c.segment); })
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('y', function(c) { return yScale(c.the_value); })
    .attr('height', function(c) { return height - yScale(c.the_value); })
    .attr('fill', 'teal');

  // call axis just on this SVG
  // otherwise calling it 5 times for 5 metrics...
  d3.select("svg." + d.value[0].parameter)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis)
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='vis'></div>
```